# Conversion of time zone from EST to IST using java script

Tags: javascript, time, timezone

Hi I am developing small web application in which i want to convert my EST time to IST time zone. I know offset value for IST time format and I am having proper time format with correct time as well. But I am not having any idea regarding this conversion.

How to convert time from EST time zone to IST? Need Help. Thank you.

Comment: Well , you need to get the current time and add or subtract the offset from it.Be wary though , `JavaScript` date object returns your system time,not the EST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a good look at the [mdn docs for the Javascript Date api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate).

You can change the hours with `setHours`. Since **IST is 9:30 hours ahead of EST**, you just need to substract. You can get **IST** and **EST** by calculating them from **UTC**, `Date.getTime()` generates a UTC unix timecode. Here's an example

```
var UTC = new Date();
var UTC = UTC.getTime() // Get UTC Timestamp

var IST = new Date(date); // Clone UTC Timestamp
IST.setHours(IST.getHours() + 5); // set Hours to 5 hours later
IST.setMinutes(IST.getMinutes() + 30); // set Minutes to be 30 minutes later

var EST = new Date(date); // Clone date
EST.setHours(EST.getHours() - 4); // set EST to be 4 hour earlier
```

Generally, the `Date` object is a pain to deal with. Thankfully, there's [this genius library called moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) that can help dealing with dates.